# Accessing environment variable in a fastcgi application

Tags: c++, apache, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I have writen a fastcGI application using C and C++

I have a free function that returns a string, if a specific environment variable has not been set. The function looks like this:

```
namespace
{
    std::string getNameString()
    {
        char * datastr_ = getenv(MY_ENVAR.c_str());

        if (datastr_)
            return std::string(datastr_);
        return DEFAULT_NAME;
    }
};
```

I then carry out the following steps (in the order given below)

1. I have edited my /etc/environment and added the appropriate environment variable
2. I confirm that the variable has been set by typing printenv on the console
3. I stop and then start the apache daemon

When I debug my application, I find that the environment variable has not been set. I suspect that the environment under which the fastcgi application is running may different from the environment 'normal' applications run under.

Does anyone know how to retrieve environment variable in a fastcgi app?

Comment: I KNEW someone pedantic would point that out. Well getenv() is not C++ either ...

Comment: There's nothing pedantic about it, it's just plainly incorrect. It's either C or C++, and this is not C. `getenv` is a library function, nothing to do with the language.

Comment: "It's either C or C++": Don't be silly - you CAN have code that uses both C and C++. The code I have written intermixes C and C++ - and links to both the libfcgi and libfcgi++ libraries (I merely posted a snippet of the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that fastcgi processes are spawned in a "cleaned" environment by default, given your observations. Apache certainly provides a way of [setting environment variables for fastcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#FcgidInitialEnv). This has the added bonus of being slightly less cryptic too (who expects a webservice to behave differently when /etc/environment is changed?), like this you keep "web config things" with "web config things".

Comment: Reading up on the link you provided now ... If that fails, I'll just have to resort to reading the data from a configuration file (or perhaps storing it somewhere in memcache) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could look here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html and try to set the env variable in the apache process. I have assumed latest apache version.

Comment: Thanks. I did try using SetEnv and PassEnv directives, but getenv() still returned a NULL pointer.

Comment: A FastCGI process is not an Apache process, it runs as a separate process, and Apache just make a request for such process to start (requests made the fcgi-pm). The solution is to use the configuration of the FastCGI module. If the module is `mod_fastcgi`, then [Flexo gave the good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5743405/279335)